# Setting Bluemix object storage permissions

Tags: permissions, ibm-cloud, object-storage, data-science-experience

I am currently working on a project in Data Science Experience that involves writing CSV files to Bluemix Object Storage.

There are several colleagues involved in this project and I want to know how to set Bluemix permissions so that everyone can access the Object Storage container for the project through their respective Bluemix account.

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix Object Storage services does not support access control for Bluemix platform users.